# How do I edit the Wordpress post.php file?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-admin

I have a Custom Post Type which contain a Gravity Form on my website. I would like to display a message on the back end of the Post when logged in as admin. The message will say when the form has reached its entry submission limit.

The file that displays the post content in the back end is the `post.php` file but I am not allowed to edit it directly. How would I go about achieving this functionality? I already know what I need to do to check if the form has reached it's limit but how would I have this replicated in the back end.

Comment: Not that you should do it, but what exactly does it mean "I am not allowed to edit it directly."?

Comment: I get an error that says that I am not allowed to edit the file. It has to do with not having write permissions one would guess.

Comment: that is a very good thing, but do you have any access at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to add a custom meta box, and put your code in the corresponding callback.

It sounds like you've already set up your custom post type, so just make sure you have the last line to register your meta box callback:

```
register_post_type( 'wpse_cpt',
        array(
            'labels' => array('all','the','labels'),
            'public' => true,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments' ),
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'rewrite' => array("slug" => "wpse-cpt"),
            'menu_position' => 5,
            'register_meta_box_cb' => 'add_wpse_metabox'// <- ADD THIS LINE
        )
    );
}
```

Then add the meta box

```
function add_wpse_metabox() {
    add_meta_box('wpse_form_limit', 'Form Limits', 'wpse_form_limit', 'wpse_cpt', 'side', 'default');
}
```

Then add the callback with the content for your meta box:

```
function wpse_form_limit() {
    if ($limit_reached) :
        echo "Limit reached";
    else :
        echo "There's room for more!"
    endif;
}
```

Your code will look different (you won't get far copying and pasting this), but this is how you'd get custom content in the admin.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeremy, my question would be where do these functions go? Do I just put them in the functions.php file?

Comment: Yeah, in a theme, that would be the spot. Good luck!